# What is different between regular Catan and Simply Catan?

Tags: catan, simply-catan

I was recently made aware of [*Simply Catan*](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/24511/simply-catan), a re-implementation of *Catan* (formerly *Settlers of Catan*). I see that it is advertised as being faster, with only a 5 minute setup and 30 minute play-time. But what are the actual differences between these games?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like the biggest differences are tile sets (multiple hexes attached together) to decrease set up time, and only 7VP needed to win for shorter games.

From the [Catan](http://www.catan.com/game/simply-catan) website:

> **Differences Between Simply Catan and the Base Game**
>
> For a quick setup, Simply Catan comes with 5 rows of tiles, printed on both sides (1x5, 2x4, 2x3). This design reduces overall setup time of the game while still providing enough variation to make for a different game each time you play.
>
> For beginners, the rules provide recommended starting positions. This allows new players to dive immediately into the fun of the game mechanics, without spending a lot of time worrying about getting started.
>
> Playing to 7 Victory Points speeds up the time to play. With Simply Catan, 30-40 minutes is all your family needs to get your "Catan fix".